# How to copy files from remote machine(other machine) using apche Camel?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Below is code for copy files(any type of file) from remote machine or any other machine which is in our LAN. How to automatically copy files Using Apche Camel.
 I want to copy images, so any method to copy only images.

I implement this in spring.

```
       final String sourceFolder = "ftp:172.30.83.119\\D:MyCLone\\WSIMS\\images?username=shailesh.bhad&password=Password2";
        final String destinationFolder = "file:D:\\outbox";

        final CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from(sourceFolder).to(destinationFolder);
            }
        });

        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        camelContext.stop();
}
```

Comment: So what is your actual question here?

Comment: I want to automatically copy  images files from another machine after scanner scan files..using apache camel in spring mvc

Comment: You can mount(shared drive) the destination folder from other machine on your local machine where the camel application is running and then make a camel route locally. With this simple solution you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

See the FTP example

- http://camel.apache.org/ftp-example.html

And then insted of sending to another FTP server, you can change the url to use the file component so it can store the files in your LAN

And see also this FAQ how to keep a Java JVM running

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: I saw that example but how or what give **from("ftp:** path and how continuous  running this using spring

Comment: Means i use **ip** but after some days **ip** will be change..so how and what give path...that is my confusion..Can you give me sample example.